# What means this javascript "double" ternary condition?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I'm a newbie in javascript learning, and I've seen an interested way of coding, but can't found the meaning of this ternary condition :

```
console.log((dirY != 0 ? dirY < 0 ? 'N' : 'S' : '') + 
            (dirX != 0 ? dirX < 0 ? 'W' : 'E' : ''));
```

It's not really the classic nested scheme that we can found in documentation...
Can someone explain please ? :)

Comment: What is unclear about this, it is just another ternary within the first one. It is simply a nested if.

Comment: Do extra brackets help? `dirY != 0 ? ( dirY < 0 ? 'N' : 'S' ) : ''`

Comment: Ooh okay, it is actually really helpful with extra brackets, thank you Hans Kesting !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the explanation of your code. Actually, ternary operator is the short form of if else condition.

```js
const dirY = 5;
const dirX = -5;

let y;
let x;

if(dirY != 0){
  if(dirY < 0) {
    y = "N"
  } else {
    y = "S"
  }
} else {
  y = ""
}

if(dirX != 0){
  if(dirX < 0) {
    x = "W"
  } else {
    x = "E"
  }
} else {
  x = ""
}

console.log(y + x)
```

Comment: Thank you Asif Jalil, now it's clear ^^